# How to run a VBScript in a Qt application without involving cscript.exe or wscript.exe?

Tags: qt, vbscript

I am writing a Qt application that calls QProcess::startDetached("wscript.exe script.vbs") to show the delete confirmation dialog in Windows.

this is the script:

> ```
> Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
> Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("-") 
> Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("-") 
> objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Delete")
> ```

the arguments for Namespace and ParseName are from the arguments passed to the script.

This may be inefficient because it opens an external application first before running the script. I was wondering if i can run VBScripts in a Qt application.

If not, what alternatives can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My VBScript is very weak, so I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do. My assumption is that you are trying to delete a folder, but want to give the user the normal confirmation box and animation while the action is occurring. If that is not correct, please let me know and I will remove this answer.

A few ideas:

- You could call the Windows API directory within your C++ code to do this. I believe the correct call would be to use [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Vista and later) or [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (pre-Vista)
- Qt already has message box dialogs. Although you might not get the *exact* same functionality as the native shell, you could use this (QMessageBox::warning) and then delete the folder using QDir. This would also be cross-platform portable.
- If you stick with the VBScript, I doubt you would see any performance issues unless this is being called many, many times in a loop or something. You know, the old "premature optimization is the root of all evil" thing.

Comment: thank you Dave, you have the right idea for what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to send a file to the recycle bin while showing the native confirmation dialog to take care of extra error handling. I have no idea how to send the file to the recycle bin in any other way, so i think your first answer solves my problem. thank you very much.

Comment: WScript isn't so bad - at least you don't get a new window like CScript. All you're doing in your VBS is creating COM objects and calling methods. I don't know QT but maybe it has methods for using COM directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the IActiveScript COM interface. You can create an instance of an interpreter that implements IActiveScript to provide a runtime for evaluating scripts. VBScript and JScript can both be used for this and a number of other third-party scripting languages also provide IActiveScript support.

The overview for working with this is you create a language runtime (an instance of VBScript for instance) then add some custom objects to it. Typically if you are embedding an interpreter into your application then exposing an Application object is a good place to start. This can be just an IDispatch interface or something more concrete with an IDL generated typelibrary and all the trimmings. Once you have added the necessary named items into the runtime you load one or more scripts. Any public functions or subroutines declared in the scripts now get exposed via the IDispatch interface of the live runtime once you switch its state to active or running. To actually run the script program, I invoke the Main function for my stuff - you could choose some other scheme as applicable to your environment.

The nice thing about ActiveScripting, is to change language you just change the runtime CLSID. So if people prefer Perl they can use PerlScript or PythonScript etc. Your Application object remains the same hence you don't have to write additional code to support the new languages. The only requirement is that everything is COM.

Comment: i do believe your answer does solve my problem, but it is rather overkill for such a simple objective.

i only want to show the native confirmation box for "delete" and send the file to the recycle bin.